# Hiding/Showing Selects based on a Select choice on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html

I have 1 master select with 3 choices.
I used an onclick event on those choices to show one of the selects and hide the other two.

After I'm testing my web app on my phone and it doesn't seem to work even after I switched from onclick to addEventListener('click',function(){ stuff });

I also tried using the ontouchstart event and it also won't work. Here is my code :

**This is the master select :**

```
<select name="list" required id="list">
                <option disabled selected value> Choisissez votre groupe </option>
                <option value="1" id="g1" ontouchstart="l1();" >Liste 1</option>
                <option value="2" id="g2" ontouchstart="l2();" >Liste 2</option>
                <option value="3" id="g3" ontouchstart="l3();" >Liste 3</option>
            </select>
```

**These are the ones that will be hidden/shown :**

```
    <select name="liste1" id="l1" style="visibility: hidden " >
                <option disabled selected value> Choisissez votre source </option>
                <option > A </option>
                <option > B </option>
                <option > C </option>
    </select>
    <select name="liste2" id="l2" style="visibility: hidden " >
                    <option disabled selected value> Choisissez votre source </option>
                    <option > D </option>
                    <option > E </option>
                    <option > F </option>
    </select>
    <select name="liste3" id="l3" style="visibility: hidden " >
                    <option disabled selected value> Choisissez votre source </option>
                    <option > D </option>
                    <option > E </option>
                    <option > F </option>
    </select>
```

**This is the javascript I use :**

```
 <script>
        function l1(){
            document.getElementById('l1').style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById('l2').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('l3').style.visibility="hidden";
        }
        function l2(){
            document.getElementById('l1').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('l2').style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById('l3').style.visibility="hidden";
        }
        function l3(){
            document.getElementById('l1').style.visibility="hidden"
            document.getElementById('l2').style.visibility="hidden"
            document.getElementById('l3').style.visibility="visible"
        }

        var g1 = document.getElementById('g1');
        g1.addEventListener('click',function(){ l1(); });
        var g2 = document.getElementById('g2');
        g2.addEventListener('click',function(){ l2(); });
        var g3 = document.getElementById('g3');
        g3.addEventListener('click',function(){ l3(); });
    </script>
```

I will also a picture of what picking an option from my phone looks like.
[Select on mobile phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCOSz.jpg)

I would like to add that this works without any issues on my PC, The issue is with my Smart Phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use onchange event handler on select element instead of onclick.

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
list.addEventListener('change',function({target: {value}}){
   if (value==='1')l1(); 
   if else (value==='2')l2(); 
   if else (value==='3')l3(); 
});
```

I added it to my code pen as well
https://codepen.io/jegatheesprana/pen/BaRvwdr